# Action on every nth node creation

Tags: 7

I have a content type of event. I need to send all users an email after each 5th events saved, listing this 5 recently created events. What would be the most proper way to do that? I am tending to use `hook_node_insert` but I'm not sure how to check if it is the 5th node after the last email sent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could run an [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) on [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) to count all of the nodes of type event and then see if that count plus one (because the new node isn't saved to the DB yet) is divisible by five. Something like this:

```
function mymodule_node_insert() {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'event')
    ->execute();
  $count = (count($result['node']) + 1);
  if (!($count % 5)) {
    // Generate/Send your email
  }
}
```

Note that the code above is totally untested.

Comment: Wow! Makes sense. I'll try that tomorrow, many thanks!

Comment: Thanks, the the idea worked great! I didn't use EntityFieldQuery, but the idea counts ;)

Comment: I've used `db_select` instead. `$query = db_select('node', 'n')->condition('type', 'event'); $query->addExpression('COUNT(nid)', 'node_count'); $result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc(); $count = $result['node_count'] + 1;`

Comment: Glad it worked. I can't think of any reason `EntityFieldQuery` is any better than `db_select` - maybe better or at least "more correct".

Comment: They both have pros and cons regarding the context. In my case all I needed was the amount of the nodes of a type, so I used db_select with a query that returns only what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the Rules module and the Goals and Tasks module.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do that programmatically. Adam's answer is what was I need.